# Print out a list of prime numbers in python

Tags: python, function, loops

The question is: print out all numbers from 1 to 1000 that satisfy the two conditions:

1. Those are prime numbers
2. The numbers after being reversed are also prime numbers.
   e.g., 13 satisfies (as 13 and 31 are prime numbers), but 19 does not satisfy (19 is a prime number, while 91 is not).
   My codes:

```
def prime(n):
  if n<2:
    return False
  for i in range(1, n):
    if n%i == 0:
      return False
  else:
    return True

def reverse(n):
  List = []
  while n>0:
    List.append(n%10)
    n = n//10

  string = [str(integer) for integer in List]
  a_string = "".join(string)
  result = int(a_string)
  print(result)

L = []
for i in range (1, 1000):
  if prime(i) == prime(reverse(i)) == True:
    L.append(i)
print(L)
```

Mine seems to contain some errors as the outcome is not as expected, either it shows none or still shows 19 in the list.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your code gives a `TypeError`, logically

Comment: Try removing the `==True` in your if statement `prime(i) == prime(reverse(i)) == True`.

Comment: you can replace `if prime(i) == prime(reverse(i)) == True:` to `if str(prime(i)) == str(prime(i))[::-1]` this will be helpful

Comment: You probably want `if prime(i) and prime(reverse(i))`

Comment: @DeepakTripathi not at all at all at all

Comment: @azro Why  it can help him in reversing the number if its not float or negative?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi you reverse the boolean value given by `prime`

Comment: @azro Ohh sorry my bad. My intent is to reverse the number only but I missed that he is returning the bool value.

Comment: @azro condition should be `prime(i) and (str(i)==str(i)[::-1])`

Comment: I tried all the ways in the comments but there's still nothing in list L

Comment: @Jessie change `range(1,n)` to `range(2,n)` then change the if condition that I have mentioned. Then try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First your prime method is wrong, because the loops starts at `1`, and every numbre satisfies `n%1 == 0` , it needs to starts at 2

```
def prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

---

Then your `reverse` method returns nothing so `reverse(5)` gives `None`, you have tried it manually.

```
def reverse(n):
    values = []
    while n > 0:
        values.append(n % 10)
        n = n // 10
    return int("".join(map(str, values)))
```

---

Then simplify the condition to be

```
for i in range(1, 20):
    if prime(i) and prime(reverse(i)):
        L.append(i)
```

---

The reverse process can be done with string also, and so short that it can be inlined

```
L = []
for i in range(1, 20):
    if prime(i) and prime(int(str(i)[::-1])):
        L.append(i)
```

Comment: Thanks, may I ask this question? In the "prime" function, why cant I write else before "return True"?

Comment: @Jessie You could use `for/else` but it is useless here. It is only usefull when you may use a `break` in the loop based on the condition, to execute the else if NO break has been used, here as there is a return inside that ends the method, the "else" would be useless

Answer (score 2):

It would seem running `prime` twice is very inefficient. I would recommend the following:

```
def prime(n):
  if n<2:
    return False
  for i in range(2, n):
    if n%i == 0:
      return False
  return True

l = [i for i in range(1, 1001) if prime(i)]
print(*(x for x in l if int(str(x)[::-1]) in l))
```